# How do 3d games typically solve "symmetrical" issues on a plane made of quads?

Tags: 3d, mesh, plane, symmetry

EDIT: Got my answer, thanks!

Sorry for the vague question, I will try to be as detailed as possible.

I am currently programming a simple 3d tilemap where the Y value of the vector is something that can change. This typically affects the 6 surrounding triangles in the following manner: [Quads](http://puu.sh/odxnz/6aa33ba3c4.png)

This however isn't "fully symmetrical", so that each corner is identical and either only "4" or all of the surrounding triangles would be used instead like: [Desired effect](http://puu.sh/odxER/4c9edab16d.png)

Now what I am wondering, is there any particular/ideal ways that games use to achieve the desired effect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way to achieve that is with tessellating regular shapes, for which the situation at each corner would be identical. In your case it would be _equilateral_ triangles.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was able to solve the problem using this though in a slightly different manner:

I created an array that contains a byte whether or not the triangle is rotated or not, allowing me to manually (And depending on the situation automatically) rotate them in the way I wish to.

Comment: Here's a picture for a bit better detail: http://puu.sh/oeelx/b6a5207d9c.png